# PKPaymentAuthorizationController delegate does not called

Tags: ios

I have NSObject class in that i need to show apple pay. So I am using PKPaymentAuthorizationController instead of PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.
Apple pay sheet is displayed but delegate method does not called. How should i set delegate to my controller. My iOS version is above 11
Here is my code.

if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]]) {
NSLog(@"Can make apple pay payment");

```
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [self paymentRequest:@"10"];
    paymentContr = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:paymentRequest];

    paymentContr.delegate = self; // here self is MyClass: NSObject

    [paymentContr presentWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(@"present");
    }];

}
```

Comment: Any update here? I've just run into the same issue

Comment: Did you figure it out?